# find exact word in a var string in PHP

Tags: php, strpos

i'm trying to find an exact word inside a string.

example:

```
$word = "Many Blocks";

if (strpos($word, "Block")){
  echo "You found 1 Block";
}

if (strpos($word, "Blocks")){
  echo "You found many Blocks";
}
```

The problem here is both if are true.. and i need to find only if is the same word..

Comment: You should use regex for this.

Comment: I didn't know Reggie had an ex *Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Several Ralph.* The man has been married more times than Zsa Zsa Gabor @Fred-ii-

Comment: You mean Reggie's no longer going out with Archie? @JayBlanchard you do know that there's a few version of that comic strip *Sam* ;-)

Comment: *I do Ralph* and I am partial to Veronica myself @Fred-ii-

Comment: Yeah, she's a *va-va-va-voom'er* alright *Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: You guys are adorable.

Comment: *"and i need to find only if is the same word"* - same word, or exact match for it? hard to say what you mean by "same word".

Comment: Truth @DavidWyly. Truth.

Comment: You know guys i'm not expert like you.. that's why i'm asking here.. second, maybe as i'm not engish my explanation is not the best or well expressed.. so put some effort to help, not just came to put negative comments..

Comment: you've been given answers below; try them out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jay Blanchard says you need to do it with regex in following way:--

```
$word = "Many Blocks";
if ( preg_match("~\bBlocks\b~",$word) )
  echo "matched";
else
  echo "no match";
```

Comment: that's what I was planning on proposing, but the OP's question is a tad bit unclear for my taste right now.

Comment: Thanks you very much, preg_match will do the trick.. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to all who vote up and you that you got your answer perhaps.

Comment: Yeap! sorry i can't give you a vote up since i'm too new here..

Comment: No prob , it's cool to solve problems.

Answer (score 3):

Your code would work with an offset on the second search  and a few other changes.

```
$result = 'You found no blocks';
$position = strpos($word, "Block");
if ($position !== false){
  $result = "You found 1 Block";
  if (strpos($word, "Blocks",$position + 1)){
    $result = "You found many Blocks";
  }
}
echo $result;
```

by using the strpos() offset you can keep looping through until the word is no longer found.

```
  $found = 0;
  $offset = 0;
  while(true){
    $position = strpos($word,'Block',$offset );
    if ($position  === false){break;}
    $found++;
    $offset  = $position  + 1;   // set offset just beyond the current found word
  }
  echo "Found:  $found";
```

or

This one the code is simple but is slower:

```
  preg_match_all('/Blocks/',$word,$matches);
  $found = count($matches[1]);
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm a little slow but I get there eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with regex like this:

```
if(preg_match("/Block(\s|$|\.|\,)/", $string))
```

This looks for the word "Block" followed by space or dot or comma or end of string.

Comment: That is a good start on the answer, but the OP needs to search for both.